# Why scroll hides some elements when it's container have full width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, image

I have a div that is 100vw of width and is scrollable with dynamic elements. However, once you add more items, the first will suddenly disappearing once is not visible even if you try to scroll out.

This is more testable on mobile phones, once the view width is smaller.

My question is: How I can achieve a natural scroll with all items being visible with a view width of 100vw?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#images {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 35vh;
  width: 100vw;

  img {
    height: 20vh;
    width: 20vh;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [photos, setPhotos] = React.useState<string[]>([])
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => data && setPhotos(data.filter(p => p.id < 11).map(p => p.url)))
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div id='images'>
      {photos.length && photos.map((p, i) => (
        <img key={`${i}${p}`} src={p} alt='mock'/>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

[image: scroll]

Code pen: https://codepen.io/mdsp9070/full/bGeGXyg

Comment: 100vw gives you the width of the viewport which includes the scrollbar width. So ClientWidth is less than 100vw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what you mean? Flex wrap or grid will give you this effect.

```
  html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#images {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;

  img {
    height: 20vh;
    width: 20vh;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
  }
}
```

EDIT*

```
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#images {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 35vh;
  width: 100%;

  img {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 20vh;
    width: 20vh;
    margin-right: 1.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

Comment: So so... I also need that all elements be on same line

Comment: This will give you the scrollable div. Using ```vw``` as your unit of widths outside of the main container is a messy way to do in my experience. You should really define pixels for the boxes (```#image img```) and use 100% to tell flex-box to take all available within its containers / wrappers space. 

In the edit I removed the justify content center because flex-box will override a lot of css to satisfy itself and can often lead to breaks in the design. 

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! this solved! I was stuck on this around 1 week!